# Failed to install libgit2 on linux

Tags: r, libgit2

install.packages("libgit2")[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQmRC.png)
Installing package into â/ldfssz1/ST_INFECTION/P17Z10200N0246_Phage_XMF/USER/luoyunzhe/software/Rlibraryâ
(as âlibâ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package âlibgit2-devâ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

The error is right there - that package is not available for your version of R.

If you need that package I suggest you look it up on CRAN and find which versions of R are supported.